# issue assigning ajax response length to a var by jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have an ajax request that send vars by get on the url and gets xml nodes back. The ajax works good, in fact I can see the response when I debug with firebug... the problem is when I try to assign the number of nodes to a var by jquery.

this is the function:

```
function CargarTValores(){
try{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'f_func.php?f=g_tv&adm=1',
        data: {},
        success:function(result){
            alert("entro");
            var algo = 0;
            algo = $(result).find('error').length;
            if(algo>=1){
                alert(toString($(result).find('error').first().text()));
                }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Error inesperado.");
        }
    });
}catch(e){
    alert("algo paso");
}
}
```

I know that the response of the ajax is this:
    `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><error>No existen Tipos de Valores en el sistema.</error>`

so I know the length is at least 1 and if I put my mouse over the `.length` property on firebug it shows '1'.

by conclusion i think that my problem is on this line `algo = $(result).find('error').length;`

please tell what I'm doing wrong and thaks for your time ;)

Comment: Are you trying to find the String 'error' in your response?

Comment: @adeneo he doesn't appear to be trying to use the response outside of the callback.

Comment: Did you try `$(result).filter('error').length;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the datatype parameter in your ajax call `dataType: 'xml'`

Comment: thank you, I feel like a total dumb
I also deteled the toString function on the alert to get the message...
thank you again...

Answer (score 0):

Parsing your html via http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Example: <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WQU3R/1/)</kbd>

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'f_func.php?f=g_tv&adm=1',
        data: {},
        success:function(result){
            alert("entro");
            var algo = 0,
            xmlDoc = $.parseXML(result),
            $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
            error = $xml.find("error");

            algo = $(result).length;
            if(algo >= 1){
                alert(error);
             }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Error inesperado.");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [pareXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), here's an example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/pxNn7/))

```
xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><error>
        No existen Tipos de Valores en el sistema.</error>";

xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );

window.alert($('error:eq(0)', xmlDoc).text());
```